# Cerrar un modal al comparar que perfil tienes

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, modal

Tengo un formulario modal, en el que cuando apretas *salvar*(submit) se comprueban los campos, tipo que no tengas ninguno vacío y tal y después se envian los valores.

Me gustaría hacer, dentro de mi función, que cuando este todo correcto, se mire una variable de $_session que contiene un perfil, si es perfil es "invitado" **te salga una alerta("No tienes permisos!") y se cierre el modal(sin enviar nada obviamente)**

¿Como podría arreglar mi función para que hiciera eso?

Este es mi **modal** con `onsubmit="return validaCampos();">`

```
<div class="modal" id="nuevoUsu" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labellebdy="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>Nuevo Producto</h4>                       
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                   <form action="insertar.php" method="GET" onsubmit="return validaCampos();"> 


                           <!--campos del formulario--->


                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Salvar">
                   </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Aqui tengo la **función**

```
        <script>

        function validaCampos(){
            //etc
            //etc
            //etc
            if(cantidad < 0){
            toastr.error("Mínimo permitido 0","Aviso!");
                return false;
            }
            ////////////////////// Aquí supongo que seria la funcion
             <?php 
             if($_SESSION['perfil']=="invitado"){
             ?>
             alert("No tienes permisos, eres invitado");
             dialog.dismiss();
             <?php 
             }
             ?>
            /////////////////////
            }
            </script>
```

La alerta se me muestra pero **no se me cierra el modal y se envian los datos**

¿Como podría solucionarlo?

Gracias.

Comment: Aquí de nuevo yo. Pregunta: ¿Qué es `dialog`? ¿Cuándo lo declaras?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya que estás utilizando `Bootstrap` lo mejor es que utilices un `modal`

La idea es algo así:

```
//Si queremos que se cierre la de nuevo usuario después de la de sin permisos
            $('#divSinPermisos').on('hide.bs.modal', function () { 
          $('#nuevoUsu').modal('hide');
      });  

//Aquí iría la lógica de la $_SESSION
            if(true)
            {
              $('#divSinPermisos').modal('show');
              //Lo cerramos a los 3 segundos
              console.log($('#divSinPermisos'));
                   setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#divSinPermisos').modal('hide');                   
                }, 3000);
             //Cerramos el modal principal

             return false;
             }
           }
```

Aquí te dejo un [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kiko_L/7zu562mp/31/)

Creo que te faltaba la parte del `return false` para evitar el `submit`

Answer (score 1):

La función que utilizas para cerrar el modal no existe, por eso solo te muestra la alerta mas no se cierra el modal. Lo que debes usar es `dialog.modal("hide");`  para cerrarlo. A modo de ejemplo incluyo las variables de cantidad y dialog que asumo debe ser el modal y funciona perfectamente.
Fuente : [Boostrap Modal](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp)

```js
function validaCampos() {
  //etc
  var cantidad = 0;
  var dialog = $("#nuevoUsu");
  if (cantidad < 0) {
    alert("Mínimo permitido 0", "Aviso!");
    return false;
  }
  ////////////////////// Aquí supongo que seria la funcion

  if ("invitado" == "invitado") { // a modo de ejemplo pongo esto

    alert("No tienes permisos, eres invitado");
    dialog.modal("hide");
    return false;
  }

  /////////////////////
}
```

```html
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#nuevoUsu">Abrir Modal</button>
 
<div class="modal" id="nuevoUsu" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labellebdy="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>Nuevo Producto</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="insertar.php" method="GET" onsubmit="return validaCampos()">


          <!--campos del formulario--->


          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Salvar">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```